# Crash after debian installation

Tags: debian, installation, crash

While installing debian, in section partition, I have selected partition with old windows data with 192GB and set the option "bootable off" to on. After that the screen was black. I do not usually do installation often, so I am quite newbie to that, but does that mean - that big partition is beign prepreared to be formatted? or is that crash? I cannot do anything, power button does not react. What happened?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Installer should return to the partitioning screen.

Comment: Is it possible to have unable grafic, and thus see nothing? Cannot even turn on pc

Comment: This may sound stupid, but check if the power cord is connected correctly. If it is, the hardware has clearly failed. Hard to say what exactly, my guess would be the PSU or motherboard.

Comment: i have laptop `acer swift sf314-54`, but this have never happened before